# Cannot execute telnet commands using PHP shell_exec()

Tags: php, networking, telnet, email-validation, shell-exec

I am trying to do a mail verification using telnet and php. The whole process words fine in the terminal, but when I use php `shell_exec()`, it only runs upto the Telnet connection command. Once telnet is connected, the remaining telnet specific commands don't work anymore.

Is there some other way that we need to execute telnet using php?

**UPDATE**: I am trying to replicate [this](https://www.webdigi.co.uk/blog/2009/how-to-check-if-an-email-address-exists-without-sending-an-email/) tutorial.

Here's my Code

```
public function mailtest(Request $request){
        //Taking input email
        $email = $request->input("email");
        $divide = explode("@", $email);
        //Find out the Domain
        $server = $divide[1];
        $response = shell_exec("nslookup -q=mx $server");
        //Response of the nslookup
        print_r($response);
        $mailServerList = explode(PHP_EOL, $response);
        $line = $mailServerList[4];

        $serverArr = preg_split('/\s+/', $line);
        $n = sizeof($serverArr);
        $mailServer = $serverArr[$n-1];
        //Printing out the mail server out of the nslookup response
        print_r($mailServer);
        //Executing Telnet command
        $telnet = shell_exec("telnet $mailServer 25");
        print_r("telnet response ".$telnet);

        //Telnet Helo
        $helo = shell_exec("Helo testing.com");
        print_r("Helo response ".$helo);
        //Telnet mail from 
        $from = shell_exec('mail from: testing@gmail.com');
        print_r("MAil from response ".$from);
        //Telnet RCPT to
        $finalResponse = shell_exec("rcpt to: $email");
        print_r("Mail to response ".$finalResponse);
    }
```

And here's the response

```
Server:     10.0.80.11
Address:    10.0.80.11#53

Non-authoritative answer:
gmail.com   mail exchanger = 5 gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
gmail.com   mail exchanger = 10 alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
gmail.com   mail exchanger = 40 alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
gmail.com   mail exchanger = 30 alt3.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
gmail.com   mail exchanger = 20 alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.

Authoritative answers can be found from:
gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com  internet address = 173.194.64.27
gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com  has AAAA address 2607:f8b0:4003:c02::1a
alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com internet address = 173.194.219.27
alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com has AAAA address 2607:f8b0:4002:c03::1b
alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com internet address = 64.233.190.26
alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com has AAAA address 2800:3f0:4003:c01::1b
alt3.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com internet address = 74.125.141.26
alt3.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com has AAAA address 2607:f8b0:400c:c06::1a
alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com internet address = 173.194.205.27
alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com has AAAA address 2607:f8b0:400d:c02::1b

gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.telnet response Trying 2607:f8b0:4003:c02::1a...
Connected to gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
Helo response 
MAil from response No message, no subject; hope that's ok
Mail to response
```

Comment: as an alternative try php's `imap` extension and `imap_*` functions

Comment: @AlexAndrei Sorry but, what does it exactly do?

Comment: the extension provides functions that allow you to operate over the `IMAP` protocol, see here http://php.net/manual/en/book.imap.php

Comment: @AlexAndrei Sorry, I don't have much idea regarding this, but, can you tell me if it is going to help with email validation? or executing Telnet commands?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After taking some reference from @Lavi's answer, this is how I managed to solve the situation. `fputs` did the trick, instead of `fwrite`

```
$connect = @fsockopen($mailServer, 25);
if($connect){
    fputs ($connect , "HELO $mailServer\r\n");
    $out = fgets ($connect, 1024);
    $details .= $out."\n";

    fputs ($connect , "MAIL FROM: <$fromemail>\r\n");
    //$from = fgets ($connect, 1024);
    fputs ($connect , "RCPT TO: <$toemail>\r\n");
    //$to = fgets ($connect, 1024);
    fputs ($connect , "QUIT");
    fclose($connect);
}
```

Comment: this worked perfectly, but i had to change the position of the fgets as 4 of them are required to get all of the information that was getting output

Comment: It is syaing valid to invalid email also ::(

Answer (score 4):

shell_exec is not suitable for that (see Ulrich's explanation).

`fsockopen` should do the trick.

```
$fp = @fsockopen('yourMailServer.com', 9001);      

if ($fp) { 
    fwrite($fp, "username\n");
    fwrite($fp, "password\n");

    while ($line = fread($fp, 2048)) {    
       // do things with $line    
    }    
} else {    
    //return error    
}
```

Comment: basically I want to do a `telnet myMailServer.com 25` to start the connection, and then start with `Helo hi` and so on as shown in this [Tutorial](https://www.webdigi.co.uk/blog/2009/how-to-check-if-an-email-address-exists-without-sending-an-email/). I tried to use `fsockopen` but it didn't seem to work. Can you check the tutorial once and see how I should approach with `fsockopen` or whatever way you think would serve the purpose?

Comment: For each green line in the tutorial, you should invoke a fwrite command. And for each blue line you should read (and act upon) the $line param inside the while loop.

Comment: So once, the `@fsockopen('yourMailServer.com', 25);` is successful, I start off with `telnet yourMailServer.com 25`? or does the `fsockopen` command serve the same purpose?

Comment: fsockopen replaces the telnet. it opens a socket.

Answer (score 1):

`shell_exec()` starts a new process. It first starts a shell which then executes the given string as commands. You can not use multiple `shell_exec()` commands to interact with the same shell, like remote-controlling a terminal.

What I would do in your case is to try to build on existing code. For example, there are a bunch of existing [PHP SMTP libraries](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=php%20smtp%20library). I'm pretty sure that at least one of them will be able to do what you want or at least show you a way in which you could implement the missing features.

If you really insist on rolling your own stuff, check out the existing answer for e.g. [interacting with command line program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14144679/php-interaction-with-command-line-program) or PHP's [`expect` module](https://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.expect.php). Unless absolutely needed, I'd avoid this though, because it is inefficient. Also, webservers are often configured to disallow starting new processes for security reasons, so if your code works when you run it from the commandline but not inside the webserver, keep this difference in mind.